# Setting working directory through a function

Tags: r, function, setwd

I am new to R. I am facing trouble setting my working directory through a function.
This is what I have tried:

```
myfunction<-function(directory)
   {
     setwd(paste(getwd(),("/directory"))

   }
```

When I run myfunction("name")
It gives error:cannot change working directory.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Try using `setwd(paste0(getwd(), "/directory")`. `paste` inserts a space.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
myfunction <- function(directory) setwd( file.path(getwd(), directory) )
```

or realizing that `getwd()` is the default so it need not be specified:

```
myfunction <- function(directory) setwd(directory)
```

or realizing that your function actually performs the same function as `setwd` this would work:

```
myfunction <- setwd
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know but if you are interested, this may be helpful as well:

https://github.com/imanojkumar/MyFunctions1/blob/master/README.md

#### Or just use the below code:

```
source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/imanojkumar/MyFunctions1/master/ChangeDirectory.R")
```

The above source file contains the below three codes:

#### 1. Ask user to give path to directory

```
directory <-  readline('Enter Path to Directory You want to set as
                        Default (use backslash e.g. "E:/MyDirectory") : ')
```

2. Function

```
myfunction <- function(directory) {
if (!is.null(directory))
   setwd(directory)
}
```

#### 3. Function runs in the background and sets the user defined directory as default

```
myfunction(directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is using "/directory". You will get the result if you just use **directory** instead of **"directory"**as in:

> myfunction <- function(directory){ 
>     setwd(directory)
>   }

If you use the paste function, the output will be a character string and at the end it will be interpreted something like change my working directory to "directory" which does not exist and hence the error. R adds its own "" and hence your function becomes setwd(""directory"").You can read more in the help for path.expand()